# Blank icon upon initial start of CDHtmlDialog window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-8, mfc, icons

I have an application written in Visual C++ 2010 I'm working on that uses CDHtmlDialog windows to create the UI.  Upon first startup in Windows 8/8.1/Server 2012, if the taskbar is set to "Combine when taskbar is full" or "Never combine" taskbar buttons (whether prior to or after first startup), the taskbar will display a blank page icon for the application.  If the dialog window is closed and reopened, the icon will be correct, even after a reboot; ie. this only happens on initial startup after install.  This does not affect Windows XP, 7, or 10.

I at first suspected icon loading within the CDHtmlDialog windows, which includes code that seems to be widely used.

```
CWindowDHtmlDialog::CWindowDHtmlDialog(CWnd* pParent)
:   CDHtmlDialog(CWindowDHtmlDialog::IDD, 0, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

BOOL CWindowDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDHtmlDialog::OnInitDialog();
    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CWindowDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDHtmlDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}
```

However, manipulating this code doesn't appear to have any effect on the window or icons at all.

Next, I suspected the icon order and available sizes in the .ico file, so I replaced it with a test icon that contained all available sizes (from 16x16x4bit to 256x256x32-bit) but to no avail.

I also attempted to check for a registry change immediately after first startup, since this issue only affects first startup, but there were also no changes (at least to registry entries relevant to our application).  Also, an uninstall resets this behaviour so that the icon is again blank after install, so this reduces the chance that it is a registry issue.

I also checked for issues in the .rc file, particularly with the IDR_MAINFRAME icon ID, but modifications to the .rc file or to the IDs made no difference.

Changing the .ico file that IDR_MAINFRAME points to does make a difference, but this is expected and I suspect that once VS does something to load the icon, it may be difficult to find a way to control what VS does with it.  Since Win XP, Win 7, and Win 10 don't exhibit the same behaviour, it may be something specific that Win 8/8.1/2012 does to taskbar icons.

Start menu and desktop icons are correct, and pinning or unpinning the taskbar icon makes no change.

The issue may very well have nothing to do with CDHtmlDialog, but I can't be certain of that.

Comment: I don't have Windows 8, but I worked on it in the past and I didn't see this error. Can you recreate the problem with a new minimal solution? or with `CDialog`?

Comment: I'm not sure that's an option at this point, as this is on a large, well established project.  The UI is all in html, so even if using CDialog worked it's not considered a solution.  I will try to create a minimal solution possibly if I can find the time, but that may only help narrow the scope slightly.

Comment: I didn't say change to `CDialog`. I suggested creating a test project with either `CDHtmlDialog` or `CDialog` with nothing in it, just to see if the display error is there. By the way, I don't know exactly which icon you are talking about it. Try restarting your Windows 8, because sometimes the icons are cached and you don't see the changes.